# rewrite urls with slashes ( %2F ) in query string

Tags: apache, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I was wondering if there is a way to handle in a rewrite rule ( iis and apache ) url query strings which contain a slash ( %2F ) as part of it.

as an example:

```
www.domain.com/project/word1
```

gets rewritten to

www.domain.com/project/index.php?word=word1

via this rule ( in iis ):

```
<rule name="Friendly">
    <match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?word={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

or in apache:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?word=$1
```

this works correctly.

however there are cases like this :

```
www.domain.com/project/word1%2Fword2
```

which should be redirected to

```
www.domain.com/project/index.php?word=word1/word2
```

but obviously i get an error 404 because of the slash ( %2F ). Is there any way to solve this ? Even if it meant I have to cut off the /word2 part and redirect www.domain.com/project/word1%2Fword2 to www.domain.com/project/index.php?word=word1

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your case peculiar because in Apache's *mod_rewrite* module (I'm not sure about IIS) it's stated that [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) *patterns* are matched against the, I quote, **"(%-decoded) URL-path (or file-path, depending on the context) of the request"**.

What I'm experiencing though after testing is that the encoded slashes are **not** decoded or not interpreted by the server (I too get an 404 error).

However, I realize one mostly url encode URL parts when the content is to be used as a *query string* argument (for example `http://www.example.com/?path=word1%2Fword2`) which is logical because you don't want the server to interpret the encoded slash as a part of the URL path. Note that this observation is contradictive to the statement above so take it with a grain of salt.

### Solution

What I can confirm however is that it's no problem rewriting `www.domain.com/project/word1/word2`. Therefore I suggest that you don't encode the pat of the URL that will be used in the *path* part, but possibly whitelist allowed characters instead so you avoid special characters like `?`.

---

### Test results

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?word=$1 [L]
```

**index.php:**

```
<pre>
    <?php var_dump( $_GET, true ); ?>
</pre>
```

**URL: `http://test/word1%2Fword2`**

Yields 404.

**URL: `http://test/word1/word2`**

Yields:

```
<?php
array (size=1)
  'word' => string 'word1/word2' (length=11)
?>
```