# IIS ARR replace encode slash %2F in query string

Tags: iis, gitlab, url-rewrite-module

I have an gitlab ce installed on VM Ubuntu-GLS inside the LAN. To give it access from internet am using IIS ARR URL Rewrite module at my primary web server. Gitlab for getting some files from repository via API requires to split catalog with forward slash encoded as %2F.
If I sending request to gitlab API like:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <myPrivToken>" "http://gitlab.mysite.com/api/v4/projects/8/repository/files/DemoAM%2F.project?ref=master"`

Where is DemoAM is folder in root repository. ARR replaces %2F on forward slash, and gitlab gets request like (i hid some non important fields from gitlab log):

```json
{
  "status": 404,
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/api/v4/projects/8/repository/files/DemoAM/.project",
  "host": "Ubuntu-GLS",
  "remote_ip": "192.168.0.1:58496, 192.168.0.102, 127.0.0.1"....
```

where %2F deplaced with /

But if I sending request directly to local VM/ like:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <myPrivToken>" "http://Ubuntu-GLS/api/v4/projects/8/repository/files/DemoAM%2F.project?ref=master"`

gitlab gets correct request like:

```json
{
  "status": 200,
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/api/v4/projects/8/repository/files/DemoAM%2F.project",
  "host": "Ubuntu-GLS",
  "remote_ip": "192.168.0.102, 127.0.0.1"....
```

where if %2F provided as is, and it's correct

I've find a very similar question here
[rewrite urls with slashes ( %2F ) in query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084135/rewrite-urls-with-slashes-2f-in-query-string)
but i can't using it's answer because I can't change gitlab request rules.
Also, without result i've tried to set up `useOriginalURLEncoding` to false as was recommended here: [Windows IIS ARR Reverse Proxy Encoding Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69163262/windows-iis-arr-reverse-proxy-encoding-issue).

**So, is the other way(s) to solve this problem? I expect to solution where rest string {R:1} will passthrow as is, without replacing encoded symbols**

I use rules like this:

```xml
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://gitlab\.mysite\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://Ubuntu-GLS/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        <serverVariables>
            <set name="HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="{HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" />
            <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
        </serverVariables>
    </rule>
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
           <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://Ubuntu-GLS/(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://gitlab.mysite.com/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <preConditions>
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
            </preCondition>
            <preCondition name="NeedsRestoringAcceptEncoding">
                <add input="{HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_ACCEPT_ENCODING}" pattern=".*" />
            </preCondition>
        </preConditions>
    </outboundRules>
```

Comment: There should be a `UNENCODED_URL` variable or something like that which may help here.

Comment: I tryed both variant with `<rules useOriginalURLEncoding="true">` and with false but all in vain

Comment: Hmm. I mean there is a variable called `UNENCODED_URL` that you can use directly in the `url` parameter -- not `useOriginalURLEncoding` which is a separate setting.

Comment: Yeah, you right, I just don't understood where I need to use this variable, when I used it as @Lex-Li wrote all become to work properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```xml
<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://Ubuntu-GLS/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

to

```xml
<action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://Ubuntu-GLS{UNENCODED_URL}" appendQueryString="false" />
```

and also change request filtering to allow double escaping.

## Reference

https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/url-rewrite-v2-1

Comment: In this case query string after "?" was truncated, but %2F is still replaced:
{
  "status": 404,
  "method": "GET",
  "path": "/api/v4/projects/8/repository/files/DemoAM/.project",
  "host": "Ubuntu-GLS",
  "remote_ip": "192.168.0.1:53947, 192.168.0.102, 127.0.0.1"...

Comment: **It work!** Sorry I not carefull read your recommendation and skip to replace R:1 to UNENCODED_URL. Also it need to set up parameter <rules useOriginalURLEncoding="false">
Thank you! Can't vote you answer because not enouth reputation, may some what do it instead of me.